# JFrame goes behind browser window when launched from an applet

Tags: java, applet

I made an applet that launches a jframe, but then the jframe goes behind the browser window? I tried frame.toFront(), but that didn't work. Here is the link to the applet http://dalpi.web44.net/

Comment: It works for me (Opera 11.50 on Ubuntu 11.04, with IcedTea-Web plugin, 1.1.1 for Java). What is your Browser/OS/Plugin combination?

Comment: my combo is firefox/windows 7 64-bit/Java Console 6.0.26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The problem is that the applet is stealing the focus from the JFrame. So I made the applet non-focusable

```
japplet.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a modal `JDialog` instead of the `JFrame`.  If you truly need to launch a `JFrame` from a web page, use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to do it, and forget the applet (and all the associated hassles).

BTW - the link in that page to the source, is broken.

Comment: I had no problems with a JFrame invoked from an JApplet, though.